# How can I convert a number from base10 to base 2 binary in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**I want to write a loop with while/for to get a num from user and convert it from base 10 to base 2 binary do you know how can I do this?**

1. I want to get number from user.
2. then specify 2 % Number == 0 or 2 % Number != 0
3. if it's equal to 0 console.log(0) and if it isn't equal to 0 console.log(1)
4. I want to if 2 % Number != 0 convert the answer to Int and then repeat steps 2 and 3!

Comment: If you are testing for zero true/false, you don't need to convert it to binary first as it will be zero (or not) in both bases. Could you explain a bit more if I have misunderstood?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very confusing. Are you asking about your attempt to build an algorithm that converts a base10 integer to base2? Or are you asking in general how to do that? Could you actually show your code?